# is there any other conky fonts besides conkysymbols?

Tags: conky

is there any other conky fonts besides conkysymbols?
I am using Conky version 1.12 and using ConkySymbols, but would like a few more symbols.

Comment: Conky supports any font installed on your system. What do you mean?